# How can I sum the individual element positions in an int[]?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have the following:

```
var a1 = new [] { 2, 7, 9 };
var a2 = new [] { 6, 3, 6 };
```

I want to end up with:

```
var sum = new [] { 8, 10, 15 };
```

What's the quickest way to get there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Zip()`:

```
var res = a1.Zip(a2, (x, y) => x + y).ToArray();
```

Also, you can use `Select()`:

```
var res = a1.Select((x, i) => x + a2[i]).ToArray();
```

Comment: Nice, never knew that one existed.